# Starting service using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am trying to start a service using Alarm Manager. I have tried everything but it just doesn't get started. I am calling the below mentioned code from a button listener of an activity.

```
    private void setAlarmManager(String interval) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                                           0,
                                                           i,
                                                           PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(interval));
        service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                                    (Integer.valueOf(interval) * 60000), pending);
    }
```

and my manifest looks like :

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.pack.android.service.MyService"
            />
```

I am trying to start a service as per the user specified time in minutes. But my service never gets called.

If i call the service using the following code, it works. My project target version is 16.

```
getApplicationContext().startService(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

change `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to `PendingIntent.getService` for starting an serivce using `PendingIntent` as :

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                                     0,
                                     i,
                                   PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```